# WSO2IS as key manager in WSO2apim error configuration

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

When I try to import well-known URL, the system return The server encountered an internal error. Please contact administrator.

The link of my well-known URL is:

https://localhost:9444/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/.well-known/openid-configuration

I follow the step in:

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-wso2is-connector/

But it keeps giving an error.

Thank you for support.

Comment: Is the WSO2 IS server running with port Offset of 1? Can you add the error getting logged on the server?

Comment: Yes, I set “offset = 1” in the .toml configuration file.
The problem was that wso2is 6.1.0 is not compatible with wso2am 4.2.0.
I downloaded the previous version of wso2is, and everything worked fine.
I also had to extract the wso2is ssl certificate and import it into the wso2am file to indicate that it is trusted.